# sum = sum + num discussion question post error in output but no errors and does not compile

Tags: visual-c++

I have submitted my discussion question response online and queried the instructor who cannot help me because his "compiles fine".  I need some help with where to get help with visual studio and learning c++

The textbook we were provided uses "namespace std".  We are not allowed to use it.  I have tried all types of while loops in the text book and all I have been able to accomplish is std::cout "Enter a number: " and I can enter a number (when that was in the code... I took it out).

This was the discussion question:

Suppose that the input is 0 0 8 12 50 7 13 -1.  What is the output of the following code:

```
int num, sum, count;
cin >> sum;
cin >> count;
cin >> num;

while (count <= 4)
{
    sum = sum + num;
    count++;
    cin >> num;
}
cout << "Sum = " sum << endl;


#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

int main()
 {
 std::ifstream inFile; //input file stream variable
 std::ofstream outFile; //output file stream variable

int num = 0;
int sum = 0;
int count = 0;

inFile.open("Unit1Question5.txt");
outFile.open("sum.out");

while (count <= 4)
{
sum = sum + num;
count++;
std::cin >> num;
}
std::cout << "Sum = " << sum << std::endl;
system("pause");
}
```

When I click debug, I get no errors but the ouput tab has:

'Unit1DiscussonQuestion5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\12345\Desktop\C++ Projects\Unit1DiscussonQuestion5\Debug\Unit1DiscussonQuestion5.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Unit1DiscussonQuestion5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. 
'Unit1DiscussonQuestion5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. 
'Unit1DiscussonQuestion5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. 
'Unit1DiscussonQuestion5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140d.dll'. 
'Unit1DiscussonQuestion5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. 
'Unit1DiscussonQuestion5.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. 
The thread 0x3eec has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x204c has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 0x3c9c has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 0x2308 has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The program '[13620] Unit1DiscussonQuestion5.exe' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to figure it out if you debug with breakpoints. Place multiple breakpoints and proceed to execute the code line by line.
Here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019) from Microsoft about how to debug with breakpoints.

As for learning c++, maybe this [tutorial](https://www.learncpp.com/) helps.
I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I will check out the links. Part of my confusion is being more of a user than a programmer. I was waiting for the prompt to enter the numbers but did not have a std::cout std::cin code to illicit input.